# Android 14 dialog gray scrim disappears

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, android-14

I recently tried the Android 14 emulator (API Level 34) and verified how dialogs look like on the new OS.

At first sight I noted that the dialog's scrim (used to be dark transparent gray) disappeared.

See for instance here (on the left Android 14 and on the right Android 13)

[image]

The strange thing is that, when taking a screenshot on the Android 14 emulator

```
adb shell screencap -p filename
```

the dark scrim is included.

Anyone out there has a clue on why this is happening?

With other emulators (different API levels), everything works as expected.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017?pli=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem on the emulator. But the dim shows again when I "Disable HW overlays" in the Developer options.

[image]

I have tested on the real device with Android 14 and only the emulator does not show dim.

Issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017